# Higher order functions and lack of recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, higher-order-functions

I'm just starting out on my Haskell journey,  and up until I met currying, partial application and higher order functions (i.e. when it starts to get interesting) I was flying - yes I know the intro stuff is easy and so is this stuff probably!)

Anyway this question is regarding higher order functions. 
Given this example from a well known tutorial

```
applyTwice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a  
applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

I can see how it works and if I suspend my disbelief I believe I understand it.  However, whats confusing me, is why this doesn't recurse.   Given the call to f (f x)  when we reenter the callback we would pattern match again, surely.  What am I missing here?

Comment: recursion would be calling `applyTwice` from within itself, not the argument function twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recursion is applying a function within its own definition. Here we don't have that situation. Let's look at what happens if we define a function `square` and use it with `applyTwice`:

```
square :: Int -> Int
square x = x * x
```

Now let's follow the evaluation of the following function application:

```
applyTwice square 3 => square (square 3) => square 9 => 81
```

Comment: Fun fact: most Haskellers would probably define `applyTwice` so it looks almost the same as `square`, namely `applyTwice f = f . f`. Perhaps this makes it even clearer that no recursion is going on, since basically we're just "squaring" a function. (Or rather doubling, if this is Church numerals we're talking about.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Which is no coincidence given the algebraic structure involved in both examples.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Or depending on whether you consider the endomorphism monoid to be additive or multiplicative. ;)

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't recurse because `applyTwice` isn't called recursively. Which might be a little tautological, so let's look at an evaluation trace.

```
inc :: Int -> Int
inc n = n + 1

applyTwice inc 3
(\f x -> f (f x)) inc 3
(\x -> inc (inc x)) 3
inc (inc 3)
```

As `f` became `inc` and `x` became `3` we see that all `applyTwice` does is take its first parameter and, well, apply it twice to its second parameter.

Comment: Apologies Ive been an idiot, I dont know why I thought applyTwice was being called within itself.  Sleep may be the cure here!